# Unable to get kafka_connect_connector_status on Promethues

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Confluent for Kubernetes to deploy Kafka Connect. For metrics monitoring I am using promethues operator and have added a job in `Secrets` name `additional-scrape-configs`. The configurations looks like this:

Secret: `additional-scrape-configs`

```
- job_name: 'kafka-connect'
  scrape_interval: 60s
  scrape_timeout: 30s
  honor_timestamps: true
  static_configs:
  - targets: [ 'dev-connect-0-internal.kafka.svc.cluster.local:7778' ]
```

ConfigMap: `connect-shared-config`

jmx-exporter.yaml

```
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false
lowercaseOutputName: true
ssl: false
```

I can see these metrics on Prometheus, However I cannot see the metrics named `kafka_connect_connector_status`.

[image: Metrics on Prometheus]

I am not sure If this is required or not but I have also added these rules in Kafka connect CRD

```
apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Connect
metadata:
  name: dev-connect
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  metrics:
    pormethues:
      rules:
        - pattern: 'kafka.(.+)<type=app-info, client-id=(.+)><>start-time-ms'
          name: kafka_$1_start_time_seconds
          labels:
            clientId: "$2"
          help: "Kafka $1 JMX metric start time seconds"
          type: GAUGE
        - pattern: 'kafka.(.+)<type=app-info, client-id=(.+)><>(commit-id|version): (.+)'
          name: kafka_$1_$3_info
          value: 1
          labels:
            clientId: "$2"
            $3: "$4"
          help: "Kafka $1 JMX metric info version and commit-id"
          type: GAUGE
        - pattern: kafka.(.+)<type=(.+)-metrics, client-id=(.+), topic=(.+), partition=(.+)><>(.+-total|compression-rate|.+-avg|.+-replica|.+-lag|.+-lead)
          name: kafka_$2_$6
          labels:
            clientId: "$3"
            topic: "$4"
            partition: "$5"
          help: "Kafka $1 JMX metric type $2"
          type: GAUGE
        - pattern: kafka.(.+)<type=(.+)-metrics, client-id=(.+), topic=(.+)><>(.+-total|compression-rate|.+-avg)
          name: kafka_$2_$5
          labels:
            clientId: "$3"
            topic: "$4"
          help: "Kafka $1 JMX metric type $2"
          type: GAUGE
        - pattern: kafka.(.+)<type=(.+)-metrics, client-id=(.+), node-id=(.+)><>(.+-total|.+-avg)
          name: kafka_$2_$5
          labels:
            clientId: "$3"
            nodeId: "$4"
          help: "Kafka $1 JMX metric type $2"
          type: UNTYPED
        - pattern: kafka.(.+)<type=(.+)-metrics, client-id=(.*)><>(.+-total|.+-avg|.+-bytes|.+-count|.+-ratio|.+-age|.+-flight|.+-threads|.+-connectors|.+-tasks|.+-ago)
          name: kafka_$2_$4
          labels:
            clientId: "$3"
          help: "Kafka $1 JMX metric type $2"
          type: GAUGE
        - pattern: 'kafka.connect<type=connector-task-metrics, connector=(.+), task=(.+)><>status: ([a-z-]+)'
          name: kafka_connect_connector_status
          value: 1
          labels:
            connector: "$1"
            task: "$2"
            status: "$3"
          help: "Kafka Connect JMX Connector status"
          type: GAUGE
        - pattern: kafka.connect<type=(.+)-metrics, connector=(.+), task=(.+)><>(.+-total|.+-count|.+-ms|.+-ratio|.+-avg|.+-failures|.+-requests|.+-timestamp|.+-logged|.+-errors|.+-retries|.+-skipped)
          name: kafka_connect_$1_$4
          labels:
            connector: "$2"
            task: "$3"
          help: "Kafka Connect JMX metric type $1"
          type: GAUGE
        - pattern: kafka.connect<type=connect-worker-metrics, connector=(.+)><>([a-z-]+)
          name: kafka_connect_worker_$2
          labels:
            connector: "$1"
          help: "Kafka Connect JMX metric $1"
          type: GAUGE
        - pattern: kafka.connect<type=connect-worker-metrics><>([a-z-]+)
          name: kafka_connect_worker_$1
          help: "Kafka Connect JMX metric worker"
          type: GAUGE
        - pattern: kafka.connect<type=connect-worker-rebalance-metrics><>([a-z-]+)
          name: kafka_connect_worker_rebalance_$1
          help: "Kafka Connect JMX metric rebalance information"
          type: GAUGE
  replicas: 1
  image:
    application: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-replicator:7.5.0
    init: confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.7.0
  internalTopicReplicationFactor: 1
  dependencies:
    kafka:
      bootstrapEndpoint: <kafka-endpoint>:9094
  podTemplate:
    podSecurityContext:
      fsGroup: 1000
      runAsUser: 1000
      runAsNonRoot: true
```

After applying the above CRD the rules are not poupulated in ConfigMap and the configMap still looks like this:

ConfigMap: `connect-shared-config`

jmx-exporter.yaml

```
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false
lowercaseOutputName: true
ssl: false
```

Adding these rules are mandatory? if yes, why are they not applied when the manifest is applied? If not, then why can't I see the metric `kafka_connect_connector_status` on Prometheus?

I expect to see this `kafka_connect_connector_status` metric on Prometheus.